# Installing iOS apps without Apple Developer Program on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, jailbreak, unsigned, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to install my iOS app on to devices running iOS 7.0. I can install them on my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1 jailbroken. But currently I'm not able to do so on a friend iPad 4 with iOS 7.0.
For installing them on JB devices I'm using [JailCoder](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/index.php?lang=en-US) .
It works without any problem and I can code and compile my test apps, and put them on JB devices without any effort.

Recently trying to investigate possibilities I found an application named PP25 for Windows, it is a chinese application and it is said to be able to install cracked apps on NON-JB devices.

So i tried to see ig it works somehow, I was able to get my apps converted as ipas from my phone and download them to desktop with it, and i can then upload on other JB devices, thanks to a Cydia application named AppSync, pretty good indeed, but I tried and wasn't able to install them on iOS 7.

That was disappointing, I made additional tests and it appears that the PP Assistant application is able to install cracked apps on iOS 7.0 too, but not my unsigned apps (fails to verify the app rights).
Indeed there is a section in the chinese application where you can download and install commercial apps on iOS 7.0, so there must be a trick they use to re-sign the apps to make it appear as it's a legit app and thus be able to upload to the device even if not jailbroken.

If someone has any idea of what they actually do to make this happen, this would be very useful to know to test apps without JB on every device.

Comment: http://www.howardforums.com/forumdisplay.php/368-iOS-Hacking-and-Unlocking and http://www.hackforums.net/forumdisplay.php?fid=137 would be two sites you might be able to post this to with better results.

Comment: Will give those forums a go.

Comment: I'm asking from a developer point of view, not by an hacker wanting a JB on iOS 7.

Looking these forums, looks like they are more into Jailbreaking, I'm not into it, also I cannot jailbreak a device that it's not mine.
My question was, how can that Chinese App for Windows, install apps on a iOS 7 not-JB device moreover considering those apps where commercial apps released on Appstore, is it re-signign them and using a special trick to bypass Itunes and upload those to the Device ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I did a little research on one of those chinese apps - Kuaiyong. It didn't resigned apps. All apps were signed by Apple which means that they are just plain AppStore apps. It used some kind of trick to load into device information about Apple ID that was used to purchase these apps. There is special button in Kuaiyong application that does this - if you push it device will display synchronization icon in status bar. Only then these apps will work. Otherwise iOS will ask you to enter Apple ID that was used to purchase these apps which again means that they're just plain AppStore apps.

Comment: These means that without Apple Developer Program, it's not possible to install an app in any case, except on a jailbroken device where you can upload an unsigned application.

Indeed the trick seems to work only for already Apple Signed apps which embed the Apple ID used to buy that app.

Answer (score 0):

Non-jailbroken devices require valid code-signing to execute binaries. Either wait for a jailbreak to surface for iOS7.X, or find a code-signing service (they are available out there).

Comment: Can you deepen about these code-signing services. Are they free ?

Anyway Don't know if you have understood completely what I wrote, but that chinese site can re-sign already signed apps and publish paid apps for free in their "store", and those can be installed on iOS 7 without jailbreak.

Are those services you mention working in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 7, you can install your app to your device using a freely available Apple ID.

> Free On-Device Development
>
> Now everyone can run and test their own app on a device—for free. You can run and debug your own creations on a Mac, iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Apple Watch without any fees, and no programs to join. All you need to do is enter your free Apple ID into Xcode. You can even use the same Apple ID you already use for the App Store or iTunes. Once you’ve perfected your app the Apple Developer Program can help you get it on the App Store.
>
> See Launching Your App on Devices for detailed information about installing and running on devices.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html)